# How to add date to android calender?

Tags: android, json, calendar, android-calendar

How to add the below date in android calender? I tried converting my date string to SimpleDateFormat. But i still don't know how to add this as beginTime.

```
2014-11-24 16:25:55+0530
```

Somebody please help...

```
String strDate = "2014-11-24 16:25:55+0530";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z");

Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
    convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(datetime);
    SimpleDateFormat sdfmonth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdftime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");


    monthday = sdfmonth.format(convertedDate);
    time = sdftime.format(convertedDate);


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Date "+monthday, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time  "+time, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(eventdate);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, eventName)
    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Your date format and string are incorrect, please correct it according to your requirment and then you can get time in millis from date object which can be obtained by parsing date string.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Date string i.e

```
String strDate = "2014-11-24 16:25:55 +0530";
```

to Date and then to time in milliseconds using the following code:

```
 try {

      String strDate = "2014-11-24 16:25:55 +0530";

      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z");

      Date d = dateFormat.parse(strDate);

      long millisec = d.getTime();

      System.out.println("Millisec :" + millisec);

      } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
```

Hope this Helps :)